# Somebody help me with my code, NO IDEA why it doesn't work - JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Well. I have imported everything, this part is right. The thing I cant get, I want JPanel p2 to be SOUTH, but it doesnt move to SOUTH. Working at ECLIPSE, it's not showing any mistakes. Except it doesnt work the way I want. Help, please

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton but1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton but2 = new JButton("Button 2");     
    JButton but3 = new JButton("Button 3"); 
    JButton but4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    JButton but5 = new JButton("Button 5");
    JButton but6 = new JButton("Button 6");
    JButton but7 = new JButton("Button 7");
    JButton but8 = new JButton("Button 8");
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    p1.add(but1);
    p1.add(but2);
    p1.add(but3);
    p1.add(but4);
    p2.add(but5);
    p2.add(but6);
    p2.add(but7);
    p2.add(but8);
    frame.add(p1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setResizable(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Please make your title related to problem you are having. Otherwise it will be harder to people with same problem find your question and potential answers.

Comment: Also `setVisable(true)` should be called when you already set-up your frame, so move this at end of `main` method.

Comment: Remove this line " frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());"

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you change the layout of your JFrame to a FlowLayout. Therefore you can't use the (default) BorderLayout of the JFrame anymore and your JPanel doesn't go south. So, just remove that line of code and it will work.

I don't see the point in setting the layout of the JFrame to a FlowLayout as the JPanel uses FlowLayout by default.